# Background of 'Eisenstein series'

Tags: number-theory

It's my first question.
I am studying elliptic function, Among them, I have a question about the Weierstrass elliptic function.
In the Weierstrass elliptic function, their coefficients are expressed by 'Eisenstein series'. So I was so curious about origin of eisenstein series. When I search about it, 'Eisenstein series' was discovered by 'Kronecker-Weber theorem' and 'Jugendtraum'.
But I want to know about this more detail.

Comment: "Jugendtraum" is a youthful dream, so I doubt this is relevant. I have tried to find the original publication(s) in which Gotthold Eisenstein introduced these series, so far without success. This is outside my area of mathematical expertise, and I *suspect* that Eisenstein's own notation may have differed significantly from the modern one, making it difficult to identify the original source (in German / French).

Comment: The relevant publication is likely: 
Gotthold Eisenstein, "Genaue Untersuchung der unendlichen Doppelproducte, aus welchen die elliptischen Functionen als Quotienten zusammengesetzt sind, und der mit ihnen zusammenhängenden Doppelreihen (als eine neue Begründung der Theorie der elliptischen Functionen, mit besonderer Berücksichtigung ihrer Analogie zu den Kreisfunctionen)."  *Crelle’s Journal* 35 (1847): 153-274.

Comment: *Crelle's Journal* is formally entitled *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik*, and a [scan of volume 35](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0035?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B3%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D) from 1847 is available online at the Göttingen Digitization Center. The table of contents reveals that Eisenstein's publications (mostly on elliptic functions) took up the entirety of issues 2 and 3 (out of the four issues comprising volume 35),

Comment: Note that the Kronecker-Weber theorem dates to 1853, the year *after* Eisenstein's death in 1852. So it would seem completely irrelevant to the origin of Eisenstein's work on elliptic functions, which he *appears* to have created largely from scratch, based on a *quick* perusal of his publication.

Comment: *Jugendtraum* was Kronecker's conjecture that all Abelian extensions of imaginary quadratic field are generated by division values of suitable elliptic functions, described in his 1880 letter to Dedekind. It was a generalization of the Kronecker-Weber theorem and became Hilbert's 12th problem. Kronecker thought that Eisenstein's series would help prove it, see [Elliptic Functions According to Eisenstein and Kronecker](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/8714). Here is a link to Eisenstein's original [1847 paper, p.195:185ff](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0035).

Comment: Thank you for all answer comments!

Answer (score 4):

Andre Weil, Elliptic functions according to Eisenstein and Kronecher, Springer-Verlag, NY 1976.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will search it

Answer (score 3):

See the book "Elliptic and Modular Functions from Gauss to Dedekind to Hecke" by Ranjan Roy.  It is a very rich source of material on the history of topics related to modular functions. Using this book I was able to answer a question I once asked here about the origin of the Jacobi product formula for the discriminant modular function $\Delta(t)$: see [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/jacobis-product-for-the-discriminant).